# Vulnerability scanner for scanning AngularJS web application

Tags: security, angularjs, scanning, url

I tried scanning my web application built with AngularJS front-end and PHP backend. But scanning with scanners like Nessus and Websecurify fails due to '#' in URL. My URL has format

`http://domain.com/webapp/index.php/base#controller/function`

Anyone can suggest a good vulnerability scanner for scanning AngularJS web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [AppCheck-NG](http://www.appcheck-ng.com/)? Their scanner is purpose built for detecting and reporting on web application vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some recommendations and a general overview of what we have used in the past and how we found their performance.

[Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp): Their *new* JS scanner just got a whole lot better, and can handle this now

[OWASP ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project): Has an AJAX spider that's been OK to use

[ESLint](https://github.com/LewisArdern/eslint-plugin-angularjs-security-rules): Has some angular rules that can be found from the link